# Splitting infinite sets with disjoint subsets

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$V=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $V=V_1\sqcup\cdots\sqcup V_k$ we will understand that $V$  is a sum of disjont subsets $V_1,\ldots,V_k$,$1 < k \leq n $ and $V_i \ne \emptyset$.

Example: If we can take $k=2$ then we can obtain easily $2^{n}-2$. Easy example, if we take $V=\{1,2\}$, then $V_1=\{1\}$, $V_2=\{2\}$ and $V_1=\{2\}$, $V_2=\{1\}$. So we have two possibilities, but if we take $V=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $k=3$, i.e. $V=V_1\sqcup V_2 \sqcup V_3$ then i cant find answers.

My question is how many possibilty occur and how it can be formulized  for $n$ and $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the restriction of not having any subset empty, each element of $V$ has $k$ choices of subset, so there are $k^n$ divisions.  Now we have to subtract the ones where one or more subsets are empty.  If we want, say, $V_1$ to be empty, each element now has $k-1$ choices, so we would say there are $k(k-1)^n$ divisions with an empty subset.  Unfortunately, we have subtracted the ones with two empty subsets twice, so we need to add them back in once.  We can choose the two empty ones in $k \choose 2$ ways, so there are ${k \choose 2}(k-2)^n$ divisions with two empty subsets.  Now we have subtracted the ones with three empty sets three times and added them back three times, so we must subtract them again.  The final answer is $$k^n+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}(-1)^i{k \choose i}(k-i)^n$$  This is a use of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: Thank you very much Ross I can understand this concept with yours answers.